# How do I link to another document in Excel 365?

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

How to do I create a link in a cell on some text to another file in Excel? It seems like this feature has changed and now forces a "mailto:" prefix to the file that I cannot remove. Clicking the link launches outlook instead of simply opening the file. I'm using the Excel desktop application, version 1705 (Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus)

Comment: It's probably assuming that because your filename contains an @ symbol, that the hyperlink is an e-mail address. Have you tried renaming the file to remove the @ symbol?

Answer (score 0):

If the filename contains an `@` symbol, it forces the `mailto:` prefix. The only solution is to rename the file without the symbol.